# Create a full excel color palette from 3 colors

Tags: microsoft-excel, colors, color-profiles

My company has a color scheme consisting of 3 colors.
In RGB:

- Blue: 25 176 230
- Green: 180 213 83
- Gray: 129 130 133

(Please don't judge the choice of colors, they are not my choice!)

I need to create a full color palette for use in charts in excel. When defining a color palette in excel it require 6 color accents to be defined (from which it makes extra shades)

Is there a tool that can extrapolate the 3 colors above to give me another 3 I can use in the theme that will work with charts etc. The idea being that slices of a pie chart are distinguishable from each other (ie v similar colors are not next to each other)?

I basically have trouble choosing the remaining 3 colors for the palette.

Comment: Adobe Kuler may help you. It is designed to create color palettes. You may at the least get some ideas from it.

Comment: @pritaeas why is this a comment and not an answer as it's very good!

Comment: @Dave: good question, didn't even notice it. Added now.

Comment: I suppose it's because I lack the design flair. I don't want to deviate from the color scheme by choosing say a red color when the scheme uses a blue and green but I still need variation between the colors so chart series are distinguishable. Kuler has solved my trouble however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Adobe Kuler](https://kuler.adobe.com/) may help you. It is designed to create color palettes. You may at the least get some ideas from it.